# When to use lambdas, anonymous functions and callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, lambda, callback, anonymous-function

Lambdas, anonymous functions and callbacks seem like a great tool. I've used them with jquery and see more and more languages adding support for them as time goes on.

All that being said, I still don't know when the programming community prefers the use of them. In reading about c++ it seems that lambdas were put into place to replace functors. In jquery, everything is done with this technique.

I can understand:

```
$("#exampleId").click(goToFunction());
```

or

```
$("#exampleId").click(function(){ .... code here ... });
```

This makes sense because it is event driven. As it loops through jquery is seeing if some sort of flag is set saying that the object with the id exampleId has click triggered.

However, it gets more confusing when looking at $.post(). Why does jquery do:

```
$.post("someurl.com", function(data){ .... use data in code here ...});
```

instead of (pseudocode below pretending $.post returns):

```
myFunction($.post("someurl.com"));

function myFunction(data) { .... use data in code here...}
```

It almost seems that $.post(..., function(){}); syntax follows the $(object).click(function(){}); syntax for consistency sake. I can respect that.

It appears that the difference is between "functional" and "imperative" paradigms.

I would say that object oriented excels in the area of encapsulating everything into small self contained parts.

Imperative is procedural and is good at explaining things as a process like a factory.

Where does "functional" have it's strengths? Is it just a different way to express the same thing and is purely up to the programmers preference, or is there a benefit I'm not seeing here that makes it critical to use?

Comment: You say jQuery as if it was one language, but it is not, jQuery is a plugin, the language is javascript. You are mixing things here, you didn't show an example using lambda, lambdas are arrow functions, `$.post` can not return anything because it is asynchronous. Callbacks are used to be triggered when something in a not known time happens. Anonymous function is another story...

Comment: `$("#exampleId").click(goToFunction());` is **not** the equivalent of `$("#exampleId").click(function(){ .... code here ... });` - in your first example you're immediately invoking `goToFunction`, not when the `click` happens.

Comment: The main reason `jQuery` uses callbacks for `$.post` is that `$.post` is (by default) asynchronous and its result isn't available right away.

Comment: unless goToFunction() returns a function